# Examples on where to prefer $L^1$ norm over the squared $L^2$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

In [Deep Learning (page 39)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/deep-learning) it is stated that:

> The squared $L^2$ norm is more convenient to work with mathematically and computationally than the $L^2$ norm itself. For example, the derivatives of the squared $L^2$ norm with respect to each element of $\mathbf x$ each depend only on the corresponding element of $\mathbf x$, while all of the derivatives of the $L^2$ norm depend on the entire vector. In many contexts, the squared $L^2$ norm may be undesirable because it increases very slowly near the origin.
>
> In several machine learning applications, it is important to discriminate between elements that are exactly zero and elements that are small but nonzero. In these cases, we turn to a function that grows at the same rate in all locations, but retains mathematical simplicity: the $L^1$ norm.

Can you list some examples in which it happens that the $L^2$ norm is undesirable (possibly in the context of Deep Learning)?

Comment: Can you clarify what part of your question has to do with $L^1$?

Comment: @AdamHughes Oops, sorry. I didn't insert the part which talks about using $L^1$. I'll update the question.

Comment: Take a look at [$\ell_1$-Magic](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/l1magic/).

Comment: It's not within the realm of deep learning, but in my thesis work I had to deal with computing the expected minimum distance of a uniformly random point in a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ to a fixed set of $n$ points. It turns out that, excluding $d=1,2$, the $L_2$ computation has no closed form solution, but it does for $L_1$.

Comment: As a general matter, the square-norm fitting of data is sensitive to observations that are "outliers" (larger than average deviations from the correct model one wants to discern), and that the $L^1$ norm (sum of absolute values error) is a practical/robust alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is referring to the fact that the derivatives $L^2$ norm depend on the whole vector. For example, let

$$f(x) = \|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2}$$
$$g(x) = \|x\|_2^2 = x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac {x_i}{\|x\|_2}$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} = 2x_i$$

Notice how the to compute the partial derivative of $g$, you only need the $i$-th component. For $f$, you need the whole vector because you need to compute $\|x\|_2$. If you have a vector $x$ with 10.000.000 elements, this could result in a big difference (depending on what you need the partial derivatives for an how you handle them).

For the relation with the $L^1$ norm; it is simply saying that the $L^1$ norm likes sparse vectors (hence sets some components exactly to $0$). Now "sets" doesn't really mean anything since it's not like the $L^1$ norm takes decisions, but in several optimisation problems if you use the $L^1$ norm you end up with sparse vectors. A prime example is the [lasso regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)), or in general an optimizations problem where a regularizer in the form $\lambda \|x\|_1$ is added. The solutions to the latter will be usually sparser than when using a regularizer in the form $\lambda \|x\|_2$